# Not being able to convert flutter project into V2 embedding

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

I am new to flutter and was trying out the Flutter clock project at https://github.com/afzalali15/flutter_alarm_clock. After building it shows Convert to V2 embedding. Then I followed the steps given by the official flutter website. after updating all the things, I am now getting these errors.

```html
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"extension-level"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
lib/views/homepage.dart:65:16: Error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class '_HomePageState'.
 - '_HomePageState' is from 'package:clock_app/views/homepage.dart' ('lib/views/homepage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'.
        return FlatButton(
               ^^^^^^^^^^
lib/views/alarm_page.dart:157:36: Error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class '_AlarmPageState'.
 - '_AlarmPageState' is from 'package:clock_app/views/alarm_page.dart' ('lib/views/alarm_page.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'.
                            child: FlatButton(
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
lib/views/alarm_page.dart:179:47: Error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class '_AlarmPageState'.
 - '_AlarmPageState' is from 'package:clock_app/views/alarm_page.dart' ('lib/views/alarm_page.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'.
                                              FlatButton(
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

could you please help me to solve these errors?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question. Please [edit] your question and copy-paste the error into the question itself instead of the images. You can format it between \`\`\` <error_output> \`\`\`

Comment: yes of course sorry. this is my first time using this site